# How to solve this Maxima value?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

So I got myself a question from the textbook for practice and I came across this question.

The difference between two positive numbers is 10. Find the numbers, if the square of greater number exceeds twice the square of the smaller by a maximum amount

This is what I could do

I took the numbers as x and y

So, x - y = 10 - i

Then the greatest number be Z.

Z = x^2 * y^2. - ii

But this didn’t give me the answer. What could be the second equation?

Btw latex isn’t supported in safari of my phone. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want $x-y=10$ and $x^2-2y^2$ is maximum.

That is, $x^2-2(10-x)^2=-x^2+40x-200$ is maximum.

A trinomial $ax^2+bx+c$ with $a<0$ has a maximum at $x=-\dfrac{b}{2a}$ (if you don't know it yet, prove it). Here that means the maximum occurs for $x=20$, hence $y=10$.

Comment: Thanks dude that makes much more sense that what I did..